# jQuery UI Slider not shown for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I use jQuery UI 1.8.16 incl. the "smoothness" theme on a text input field. In FF FireBug, I can see all necessary dependencies for the slider appear:

- jQuery 1.7.1
- UI Core
- UI Widget
- UI Mouse

The theme is also loaded and all sources are checked. When inspecting the form field, the slider seems to be attached. But for some reason the slider doesn't appear as "slider".

---

**Screenshot** including FireBug

[image]

Comment: make sure the slider css is there. That would be the only thing i can think of. Maybe you didn't check the slider option when downloading the theme.

Comment: @Matt Sounds reasonable. I unchecked everything and the datepicker is displaying fine. I thought the slider will be included, as you can uncheck if you want a theme in the download or not.

Comment: @Matt Yes, that was the problem. Don't understand that as other core plugins worked without that. Thanks!

Comment: yes some will work because there is ui-widget. So sometimes thats all it uses. For certain ones it has it's own, like slider. i'll add my comment as an answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the slider css is there. That would be the only thing i can think of. Maybe you didn't check the slider option when downloading the theme.

*Edit: Moved from the comments.* Some will work because there is ui-widget. So sometimes thats all it uses. For certain ones it has it's own, like slider.